# How can I display my social media icons at the same level as my copyright?

Tags: html, css

```css
footer.footer {
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #333333;
  position: relative;
}
.wrapper {} p.copyright {
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 40px;
  font-size: 0.7em;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  bottom: 0;
}
.social {
  font-size: 19px;
  float: right;
  color: #fff;
  padding-right: 30px;
}
```

```html
<footer class="footer">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <p class="copyright">© GROUP TITLE 2015, social media icons supposed to be there ----></p>
    <div class="social">
      <a href="#" class="twitter"></a>
      <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
      <a href="#" class="facebook"></a>
      <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
      <a href="#" class="instagram"></a>
      <i class="fa fa-instagram"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

How can I display my social media icons at the same level as my copyright line, (defining, at the bottom of my footer but not under it - see snippet)?

**HTML**

```
    <footer class="footer">
        <div class="wrapper">
        <p class="copyright">© GROUP TITLE 2015</p>
    <div class="social">
        <a href="#" class="twitter"></a>
        <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
        <a href="#" class="facebook"></a>
        <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
        <a href="#" class="instagram"></a>
        <i class="fa fa-instagram"></i>
    </div>
</div>
</footer>
```

**CSS**

```
footer.footer {
    height: 300px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #333333;
    position: relative;
}
.wrapper {
}
p.copyright {
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 40px;
    font-size: 0.7em;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    bottom: 0;
}
.social {
    font-size: 19px;
    float: right;
    color: #fff;
    padding-right: 30px;
}
```

The copyright displays at the correct position of the footer, but how can I display my social media icons on the same level (height) without setting a `padding` or `margin`?

Comment: add in .social{position: abolute}

Comment: Didn't work out, the icons just floats to the left. @Ghayel

Answer (score 2):

you can try this one:

```
footer.footer {
    height: 300px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #333333;
    position: relative;
}
.wrapper {
}
p.copyright {
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 40px;
    font-size: 0.7em;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    bottom: 0;
}
.social {
    font-size: 19px;    
    color: #fff;
    position: absolute;     
    right: 5%;
    top: 85%;
}
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/22s3jw7p/)

Answer (score 1):

```
.social {
    font-size: 19px;    
    color: #fff;
    position: absolute;     
    right: 5%;
    top: 72%;
}
```

Comment: Floats back to the right but isn't on the same level as the copyright.

Comment: you can add top: 9px; or something like that

Comment: 5% was a bit too little, so set it to 72%, I hope it's on the same level as the copyright now, thanks for your time.

Comment: @JamesSnowy will you please mark my answer correct?

Comment: @JamesSnowy we are giving our time to helping you at our earliest convenience and this is not fair you are neither marking any comment or answer as well as not marking right answer that is pity

Comment: I'm searching for another way to do this, so if anyone has a better answer, wouldn't it be pity if that answer wasn't marked as correct?

Comment: You have 3 different answers and you realize my answer fixed your problem so what you are looking for to search

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97703/discussion-between-ghayel-and-james-snowy).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. I have created fiddle for it you need to change your html structure as follows. If you don't want separately arrange the social section.

```
<p class="copyright">© GROUP TITLE 2015, 
    <span class="social">social media icons supposed to be there ----&gt;
      <a href="#" class="twitter"></a>
      <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
      <a href="#" class="facebook"></a>
      <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
      <a href="#" class="instagram"></a>
      <i class="fa fa-instagram"></i>
    </span>
      </p>
```

And small change in css:

```
.social {
    font-size: 19px;
    /* float: right; */
    color: #fff;
    padding-right: 30px;
    /* width: 100%; */
    height: 10px;
}
```

I hope this what you are looking for it.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CGmCe/12921/)